# How to add data augmentation to regression problem?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, data-augmentation

I am trying to build a CNN model for regression problem with limited number of input data with 400 sample size. The inputs are images and labels are extracted from a column of csv file. To increase the input data, I need to augment the input images and match them with existing labels. I am using rotation and flipping augmentation methods. I am not sure how existing labels should be linked to the augmented images and how the final tensorflow dataset should be created to fit the model. Can anyone help me to solve this data augmentation?

```
#load csv file
labelPath =  "/content/drive/MyDrive/Notebook/tepm.csv"
cols = ["temperature"]
df = pd.read_csv(labelPath, sep=" ", header=None, names=cols)

inputPath='/content/drive/MyDrive/Notebook/test_png_64'
images = []

# Load in the images
for filepath in os.listdir(inputPath):
images.append(cv2.imread(inputPath+'/{0}'.format(filepath),flags=(cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)))

images_scaled = np.array(images, dtype="float") / 255.0

(trainY, testY, trainX, testX) = train_test_split(df, images_scaled, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

(trainY, valY, trainX, valX) = train_test_split(trainY, trainX, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)


def rotate(trainX: tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:

    # Rotate 90 degrees
    return tf.image.rot90(trainX, tf.random_uniform(shape=[], minval=0, maxval=4, dtype=tf.float32))

def flip(trainX: tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
    trainX = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(trainX)
    trainX = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(trainX)

    return trainX
```

update with ImageDataGenerator

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        vertical_flip=True,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode="nearest")

datagen.fit(trainX)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001), loss='mean_squared_error', metrics='mse')
```

Answer (score 0):

[ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) should do the trick. It generate batches of tensor image data with real-time data augmentation.

Comment: @ Taísa Felix I updated the code with ImageDataGenerator, but I found the training and validation curves worse than before. Please see the update. I am not sure if I am doing the right thing.

Comment: 1) ImageDataGenerator goal is to define the types of data augmentation you intend to do. It's not your dataset. Your train data should be placed in a flow method, where you'll be able to insert your dataset and from this point you will be able to feed your model. 
2) You should do the fit after compiling your model. and then you can do model.fit(your parameters)
3) Try to understand this tutorial step by step (it's simple and effective) and then apply the same idea to your code: https://studymachinelearning.com/keras-imagedatagenerator-with-flow_from_directory/

Answer (score 0):

Initially you should consider whether augmentations that preserve the labels are useful, or augmentations that require matching label augmentation, or both. If I am following your code correctly, you have temperature for scalar labels. Without knowing the nature of your images, I'd guess it unlikely that rotations and flips would be temperature-dependent, thus the labels are preserved and you are all set to go with ImageDataGenerator as is. Whether or not those augmentations will help the training is hard to know without trying it. Conversely, ImageDataGenerator does have a Brightness augmentation, which is the sort of thing I could imagine being temperature dependent in an image. In that case, the labels aren't preserved and you'd have to augment them manually, because I don't think ImageDataGenerator has methods for scalar labels. In my experience, it is the latter sort of augmentations (labels not-preserved) which are more obviously useful. But to get matching label augmentation you may have to do a little more manual coding than what comes stock with ImageDataGenerator; fortunately it might not be too hard.

Some of the basic elements for matching label augmentation might go like this (this is not complete code, just snippets):

1. Set up the subset of parameters for ImageDataGenerator augmentation that make sense for your scalar labels in a convenience dict:

```
regression_aug = dict(fill_mode='nearest',
                        rotation_range=3,
                        width_shift_range=0.1,
                        height_shift_range=0.1,
```

2. Use the ImageDataGenerator method get_random_transform:

```
self.tparams[i] = self.generator.get_random_transform(self.img_dims)
```

3. Apply it to the training image, and further manually apply it to the scalar label(s):

```
batch_X[i] = self.generator.apply_transform(img[i], self.tparams[i]))
batch_y[i,0] = self.lbl[x,0] - self.tparams[i]['tx']
batch_y[i,1] = self.lbl[x,1] - self.tparams[i]['ty']
batch_y[i,2] = self.lbl[x,2] - self.tparams[i]['theta']
```

where in this example case I had scalar labels that consisted of position and orientation, such that they could be sensibly be translated and rotated during augmentation.